# Symmetric cubic graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any class of cubic graphs other than cubic symmetric graph that if we add new vertex $v_i$ lies in the edge we pick, the new formed graph are all isomorphic?

See for example this symmetric graph on 4 vertices. Note that if we pick any edge and put a vertex lies on that edge all possible resulting graphs are isomorphic.

[image: aw]

Comment: This is equivalent for the graph to be edge transitive

Comment: Thanks, it will help a lot in my research.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, your property is equivalent to edge-transitivity. A graph which is edge- but not vertex-transitive is called *semisymmetric*, the smallest cubic example being the [Gray graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_graph) on $54$ vertices.